# Calculating Future Payroll Dates

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm attempting to generate a payroll schedule with as few inputs as required. As it stands, I've got it down to just 4 inputs (5 on a SEMI_MONTHLY schedule).

Payroll is simple if you just take dates for what they are and add 14 or 15, 30 or last day of the month. But where it actually gets difficult is managing holidays and when the payroll actually runs.

**Problem**

Weekly and BiWeekly cycles do not handle a holiday correctly. I'm trying to maintain it to be as functional as possible as well as return simple values for processing and not objects.

**Example:**

```
generatePaySchedule(payPeriodOptions.WEEKLY, moment('11-04-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY'), holidays, holidayPayRules.BEFORE)
```

`Fails after 11/10/2016 holiday by setting next pay date as 11/17/2016 instead of the correct 11/18/2016`

The code is below (some ES6 sprinkled in) or you can execute the following [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXYXQK?editors=0001)

var payPeriodOptions = {
      WEEKLY: 'WEEKLY',
      BIWEEKLY: 'BIWEEKLY',
      SEMI_MONTHLY: 'SEMI_MONTHLY',
      MONTHLY: 'MONTHLY'
    };

```
var holidayPayRules = {
  BEFORE: 'BEFORE',
  AFTER: 'AFTER'
};

const holidays = [
    { name: 'Martin Luther King, Jr. Day', date: moment('01-18-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY') },
    { name: 'George Washington\'s Birthday', date: moment('02-15-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY') },
    { name: 'Memorial Day', date: moment('05-30-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY') },
    { name: 'Independence Day', date: moment('07-04-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY') },
    { name: 'Labor Day', date: moment('09-05-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY') },
    { name: 'Columbus Day', date: moment('10-10-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY') },
    { name: 'Christmas Day', date: moment('12-26-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY') },
    { name: 'Thanksgiving Day', date: moment('11-24-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY') },
    { name: 'New Years Day', date: moment('01-01-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY') },
    { name: 'Veterans Day', date: moment('11-11-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY') },
    { name: 'New Years Day', date: moment('01-01-2017', 'MM-DD-YYYY') },
  ];

var payDays = [15, 30]; // Optional - Required for payroll period of Semi-Monthly

var weekly = generatePaySchedule(payPeriodOptions.WEEKLY, moment('10-07-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY'), holidays, holidayPayRules.BEFORE);
var biWeekly = generatePaySchedule(payPeriodOptions.BIWEEKLY, moment('10-07-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY'), holidays, holidayPayRules.BEFORE);
var semiMonthly = generatePaySchedule(payPeriodOptions.SEMI_MONTHLY, moment('10-15-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY'), holidays, holidayPayRules.BEFORE, payDays);
var monthly = generatePaySchedule(payPeriodOptions.MONTHLY, moment('10-31-2016', 'MM-DD-YYYY'), holidays, holidayPayRules.BEFORE);

console.log('Weekly: ', weekly);
console.log('Bi-Weekly: ', biWeekly);
console.log('Semi-Monthly: ', semiMonthly);
console.log('Monthly: ', monthly);

/**
 * @function nextPayDate - Calculates the next pay date given a previous pay date
 * @param {string} payrollPeriods - A string representation of payroll periods (WEEKLY|BIWEEKLY|SEMI_MONTHLY|MONTHLY)
 * @param {string} lastPayDay - A date in string format (MM-DD-YYYY), which represents the last pay date.
 * @param {string} holidayPayRule - A string representation of holiday pay rules (BEFORE|AFTER)
 * @param {number[]} [payDays] - An optional array of two numbers representing dates which payroll is run each month
 * @return {string} - A date in string format, which represents the calculated pay date.
 */
function nextPayDate(payrollPeriods, lastPayDay, holidayPayRule, payDays) {
  var d = moment(lastPayDay);
  var dayOfWeek = d.clone().format('dddd');
  var payDate;

  switch (payrollPeriods) {
    case payPeriodOptions.WEEKLY:
      payDate = d.clone().add(1, 'weeks');
      break;
    case payPeriodOptions.BIWEEKLY:
      payDate =  d.clone().add(2, 'weeks');
      break;
    case payPeriodOptions.SEMI_MONTHLY: {

      if(holidayPayRule === holidayPayRules.BEFORE){
        /* 
        If lastPayDay (d) is the same or before the first pay day of the month
        then keep the month the same and change the day to be the second pay day
        of the month, unless that pay day is greater than the days in the the month
        then use the last day of the month (Example: 15, 30 - Feb. 28)
        */
        payDate = (d.isSameOrBefore(d.clone().date(payDays[0])) ?
                   (d.clone().endOf('month').isBefore(d.clone().date(payDays[1])) ? 
                    d.clone().endOf('month') : 
                    d.clone().date(payDays[1])) : 
                   d.clone().date(payDays[0]).add(1, 'months'));
        /* 
        If the last pay date was the previous month because of holiday or weekend
        then set the new date to be the second pay date of that month
        */
        if(d.isAfter(d.clone().date(payDays[1])) && d.date() !== payDays[1]){
          payDate.date(payDays[1]);
        }
      } else {
        payDate = (d.isSameOrAfter(d.clone().date(payDays[0])) && d.date() < payDays[1] ? d.clone().date(payDays[1]) : d.clone().date(payDays[0]).add(1, 'months'));
      } 
      break;
    } 
    case payPeriodOptions.MONTHLY: {
      payDate = d.clone().add(1, 'months').endOf('month');
      break;
    }
  }
  return payDate.format();
}

/**
 * @function checkDate - Checks next pay date if it falls on a weekend or a holiday
 * @param {string} date - A date in string format (MM-DD-YYYY), which represents the calculated pay date.
 * @param {{key: {{name: String, date: String}[]}}} holidays - An object of days with applicable holidays.
 * @param {string} holidayPayRule - A string representation of holiday pay rules (BEFORE|AFTER)
 * @return {string} - A date in string format, which represents the calculated pay date.
 */
function checkDate(date, holidays, holidayPayRule){
  var d = moment(date);
  var dayOfWeek = d.clone().format('dddd');

  if(dayOfWeek === 'Saturday') {
    d = (holidayPayRule === holidayPayRules.AFTER ? d.add(2 ,'days') : d.add(-1 ,'days'));
  } else if(dayOfWeek === 'Sunday'){
    d = (holidayPayRule === holidayPayRules.AFTER ? d.add(1 ,'days') : d.add(-2 ,'days'));
  }

  if (typeof holidays.find(h => h.date.isSame(d, 'day')) !== 'undefined') {
      switch (dayOfWeek) {
        case 'Monday':
          d = (holidayPayRule === holidayPayRules.AFTER ? d.add(1, 'days') : d.add(-3, 'days'));
          break;
        case 'Friday':
          d = (holidayPayRule === holidayPayRules.AFTER ? d.add(3, 'days') : d.add(-1, 'days'));
          break;
        case 'Thursday':
          d = (holidayPayRule === holidayPayRules.AFTER ? d.add(1, 'days') : d.add(-1, 'days'));
          break;
      }
    } 
  return d.format();
}

/**
 * @function generatePaySchedule - Returns a pay schedule for a year
 * @param {string} payrollPeriods - A string representation of payroll periods (WEEKLY|BIWEEKLY|SEMI_MONTHLY|MONTHLY)
 * @param {string} nextPayDay - A date in string format (MM-DD-YYYY), which represents the next (non-holiday) pay date.
 * @param {{key: {{name: String, date: String}[]}}} holidays - An object of days with applicable holidays.
 * @param {string} holidayPayRule - A string representation of holiday pay rules (BEFORE|AFTER)
 * @param {number[]} [payDays] - An optional array of two numbers representing dates which payroll is run each month
 * @return {string[]} - An array of date strings representing the appropriate payroll schedule
 */
function generatePaySchedule(payrollPeriods, nextPayDay, holidays, holidayPayRule, payDays){
  if(payrollPeriods === payPeriodOptions.SEMI_MONTHLY && !payDays){
    console.error('For a Semi-Monthly payroll period, an array of two dates must be passed into generatePaySchedule');
    return;
  }
  var payPeriods = [];
  payPeriods.push(moment(nextPayDay).format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
  var lastPayDay = nextPayDay;

  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var payDates = checkDate(nextPayDate(payrollPeriods, lastPayDay, holidayPayRule, payDays), holidays, holidayPayRule);
    payPeriods.push(moment(payDates).format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
    lastPayDay = payDates;
  }
  return payPeriods;  
}
```

Ultimately, I think this could be turned into a moment plugin and upon validating each cycling, I plan on tackling that.

*edit:* better formulate question

Comment: Is there a question, or are you just looking for comments?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've edited it to hopefully provide a better question format.

Comment: @LukeSalamone Thanks, I know where the issue is, as I stated in **Problem** section. The "solution" that I've come up with would be to return an object, but my want is to return simple date values. I'm hoping for a few more set of eyes to look at it and possibly point me in a direction or show me an error that is causing me to think the only option is to return an object.